# How to patch or replace a function in Lua (with ability to restore)

Tags: lua

I think I have missed something in the code, either my "pseudo-code" is not correct or functions are not passed by reference in Lua..
I just want a small library that allows me to patch/replace a function with another function, but with ability to restore back the patched function to its original one.

Perhaps, somebody have made such library already in the past (I just can't find it).

My current code:

```
--[[
When user wants to patch/replace/detour a variable of type "function" to equal to another variable of type "function", we should always first check user's input, that is the following question - have user supplied valid arguments.
If invalid argument is caught, then throw an error to the user.
Now we know that user have supplied valid arguments, next we should check if supplied function (that is to be patched) is already patched function, if it is then throw an error to the user.
Now we save supplied function (the one to be patched) in a global table (to allow user to restore it later using another function).
Finally, we assign a function (the one to be patched) to the second function that user have supplied.


When user wants to restore original function, we should again check user's input first, that is, have user supplied a function and if so - is it really patched.
Now we know that user have supplied valid argument, so lets restore original function by looking-up in a global table (where we saved original function).
If by any chance original function is not found, just throw an error to the user.
We have all information at this point, assign a patched function (from user's input) to the original function.
Finally, clean-up, remove original function information from our global table (as it is no longer patched).
--]]

ftbl = ftbl or {}

patchf = function(dest, src)
    assert(type(dest) == "function", "bad argument #1 (function expected, got " .. type(dest) .. ")")
    assert(type(src) == "function", "bad argument #2 (function expected, got " .. type(src) .. ")")
    assert(not ftbl[src], "destination is already patched/same source exists")
    ftbl[src] = dest
    dest = src
end

restoref = function(src)
    assert(type(src) == "function", "bad argument #1 (function expected, got " .. type(src) .. ")")
    assert(type(ftbl[src]) == "function", "source is not patched/source does not exists")
    fsrc = ftbl[src]
    ftbl[src] = nil
end

local my_function = function()
  print("Hello from my_function :D", 1)
end

local another_function = function()
  print("Hello from another_function D:", 2)
end

patchf(another_function, my_function)

another_function() -- Hello from another_function D:    2
```

As you can see, it didn't patched another_function with my_function.

Comment: Your problem is exactly that lua **is** passing the function by reference. You aren't assigning to the global variable `another_function` when you run `dest = src`. You are assigning to the local function `dest`. You need to assign to the global to replace the value of the global.

Comment: @EtanReisner Alright. Now I'm guessing I will need to make changes to patchf, instead of taking a function, I can make it take the "path" string from _G, but this would only work for global functions. Any idea how to also make it work on local functions (as seen in current code)? debug library? huh.. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes and yes (I think).

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea how to also make it work on local functions (as seen in
>   current code)?

You do not need a library for replacing a local function by another local function. Just do a simple assignment operation.

For example:

```
local fu = function()
    print "fu"
end

local fu_new = function()
    print "new fu"
end

fu()
fu, fu_new = fu_new, fu
fu()
fu, fu_new = fu_new, fu
fu()
```

Will output this:

```
fu
new fu
fu
```

Comment: How would you then patch local functions that are defined in other Lua files (out of scope)... See my point in doing such a library. What you are doing is just not a solution here (not trying to offense but you are just telling me what I already know)... This escalated from a simple assignment to huh 300 lines (code in the question is out-of-date). P.S. I have got patching done, now need to do restore :D